# Can I take multiple column values from a postgres view and make it a JSON in my base table?

Tags: postgresql, view

Is it possible for creating an insertion rule on a Postgres view, which will take pseudo columns value from the view, form a JSON and store in the base table?
eg:

Table

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamptz NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamptz NOT NULL,
    email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    extra_info jsonb NULL,
    CONSTRAINT activity_completion_requests_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

View

```
create or replace view view1 as
select
    id,
    email,
    '' as extra_data_1,
    '' as extra_data_2
from table1;
```

I need an insert rule here which will take values of extra_data_1 and extra_data_2 from the view and create a JSON like `{"extra_data_1": the value of extra_data_1 from the view, "extra_data_1": the value of extra_data_2 from the view}`
How can I achieve this?

I would prefer not to add extra_data_1, extra_data_1, etc as columns in the table since those fields can be changed and added more also it does not fit into the schema.
Also, I need to expose these fields as a sperate column in the view.

Comment: What do you mean by *insert a rule*? Also, your view explicitly defines the two extra columns as empty strings, so it is unclear which result you want; sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: So the idea is the client will insert value to those empty columns, which will get stored as a JSON in the base table as {"extra_data_1": value_1, "extra_data_2": values2}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is easily possible with an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on the view. Just use `jsonb_build_object` inside the `INSERT` statement to construct the JSON from the attributes of `NEW`.

But I want to discourage such a practice. Better would be to have the base table with individual columns, then you need no view at all. There is no advantage to this implementation that I can think of, but several disadvantages:

- You cannot have constraints on the columns.
- Joins using the columns will be very inefficient.

Comment: Thank you. The use case here was to accept the values to a JSON field. The extra fields do not fit into the table schema and not necessarily relevant in joins